# How to make an indie app to "belong" to the legal company?

Tags: copyright, trademark, limited-liability-company, copyright-transfer

Lets say I have a created an app that I now want to start a company for. Company will be a 1-person company who's only product will be this app. What will define that from now on the app's intellectual property belongs to the company? Is it a license agreement, website, patent, trademark or anything else?

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133543/discussion-on-question-by-ribtoks-how-to-make-an-indie-app-to-belong-to-the-le).

Comment: I am considering a similar setup and wrote a related question here in the forum, maybe helpful for your considerations: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/59238/licensing-self-written-software-and-trademark-to-the-company-which-i-own

Answer (score 4):

There are basically two kinds of things one could do.

One could assign or transfer intellectual property rights and contracts related to the app to the entity, or one could license the intellectual property rights to the entity.

Generally speaking, in a related party transaction, everything should be in a signed writing, and a notice of the transfer of an intellectual property right that has been registered or filed with a government agency should be provided to the government agency in question.

Since there are potentially copyright, patent, trademark, publicity, and contractual rights that might be associated with the app, each aspect which exists should be transferred or licensed, as the case may be.

While the forms to do this aren't particular long, the concepts involved and correct terminology are subtle, so this would not be a wise undertaking to attempt on a do it yourself basis.